# Review inverter design: why are there no short circuits?

Tags: circuit-design, inverter, h-bridge, 555

I made my first inverter design and I got a lot of help from this website. But I want to get your suggestions before something goes wrong. Circuit output is 12V AC 72Hz square wave.

[image]

I used NE555 as frequency generator to get 12V-0V pulse signal (72Hz). When the pulse signal is high (12V) Q3 opens and output is 12V. When the pulse signal is low (0V) Q4 opens and output is -12V.

**Also I don't understand why no shortcuts happen in here?**

Q5 transistor converts NE555's 0V signal to 12V signal for Q4.

Also I'm sorry if you had trouble to understand it, my English is little rusty.

Comment: Normally, "open" means a switch is not conducting and "closed" means a switch is conducting. It's not like a door. And I think by "shortcut" you mean "short circuit"? Where are you expecting a short circuit to happen?

Comment: @DKNguyen an inverted door? :)

Comment: @SolarMike An upside down door still behaves identically to a right side up door. Perhaps you mean an inside-out door. (Mordecai: Just ignore this, we're both just talking nonsense).

Comment: @DKNguyen we can go through an open door, but electricty cannot go through an open switch ...

Comment: I'm sorry for inconvenience , electrical terms changes between languages and I meant when Q3 or Q4 closed why short circuit happens but now I understand it thanks to the comments

Comment: I'm planing to use this circuit to drive high frequency transformer . Do you think this circuit can be suitable for it ?

Comment: You might be experiencing shoot-through. That's where both Q1 and Q3 are conducting or both Q2 and Q4 are conducting. This occurs because you switch transistors on and off at the same time, but some of them are turning off slower than others are turning on.

Comment: I used 2N3906 and 2N3904 . Are they suitable or I should change them ?

Comment: @DKNguyen Your warning happened. When the frequency is low everything good but when I raised the frequency about 11 kHz short circuits started .Should I change the transistors or switch to the L293 ?

Comment: Use a uController, and npn transistors on top with a deadtime between the two signals. Life will be more easier. NE555 is not a reliable frequency generator, its duty cycle is not constant when you vary frquency.

Comment: Like arduino or Pic ?

Comment: Yes. Arduino or PIC. You can still keep PNP on top (not as efficient as NPN but simpler at lower voltages). The main thing is to drive each transistor independently. At higher frequencies, additional circuitry is required to drive the transistors so they turn on and off fast enough. So there could be two things causing shoot through at higher frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but just to help with terminology.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHLCCw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. In switches "open" and "closed" refers to the gap between the contacts.*

Comment: So if I understand it correctly : when the Q4 conducting it opens Q2 and yellow wire outputs 0V .Q1 is normally closed but Q3 not conducting so and blue wire outputs 12V ? But I don't know why Q4 effects Q2